# Create stacks on dock and rename category in `Lauchpad`

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, dock

How can I create icon stacks on dock? For example, I want stack the icons of `Word`, `Excel`, and `Powerpoint`.

Next is can I rename an application category in `Lauchpad`?

When I drag & drop an application icon onto another, a new category will be created named `Production`(or `Product`? I can't remember exactly, and no Macs at hand currently). I want to rename the category to something meaningful.

Comment: Rename the Launchpad categories, by opening the category, and simply clicking on the category name. You can then edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename a category by opening it and clicking the title:

[image]

Stacks are just folders. Put aliases to a folder and then drag it to the Dock:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you please suggest any mac tutorial for a layman :)? Thank you again.